# How to convert a C# Queue into a binary datatype to be stored as a SQL Blob?

Tags: c#, sql, queue

How do I convert a C# Queue into a binary variable, so that I can store it as a blob in SQL?

Help appreciated!

Soham

Comment: This is usually a bad idea. Why do you want to store it as a blob rather than storing the individual elements?

Comment: storing as binary leaves you open to a lot of problems if you change the footprint of your classes etc, storing as individual elements in SQL or even xml serialization would be better

Comment: The issue I am facing is, I have an object, which contains a queue of Queue Class. I am storing each object as a row in a table. The properties being made to store as individual fields in the table. How do I store a Queue in that case? Or if needed, I can change it to a simple array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301761.aspx). The easiest way might be to serialize the objects that are stored in the queue in their order, store them into your BLOB, then enqueue them on deserialization into a new Queue.

Comment: Yes, thanks Axary, I have thought about serialization. But then, how do I access and store the serialized data to be stored into a db table?

Comment: In C#, you could serialize something using BinarySerializer into a MemoryStream, then get MemoryStream's byte[] array and save that byte array into the database (BLOB=byte array)

Comment: AXARY, though I am in process of testing it, but I think this is going to work out well. So I have marked it as accepted answer. Any other roadblocks I am going to ask you :)

Comment: Axary,for binary serialization, a stream is required. Usually the streams I have worked with use a filestream and dump it in a .dat file or a .bin file for that matter. Is it possible to not dump in a file but in an SQL cell of type blob?

Comment: use MemoryStream that is mapped to memory. As I have said before, you can then "convert" the MemoryStream to byte array and save the byte array into the database